# How to get all links avaliable from server on some port?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

So I have lots of links like address:port/Bla-bla/bla-bla/file/blabla234times/ created by some server (like VLC) how can I get all links (list of them) avaliable from server (abstract server working on windows) from my C# programm?

So how to get a list or URLs of ALL existing files and folders on server. We have adress and port. (no HTML pages nothing - just server adress)

I want to scan a server to retrive its links

Comment: What exactly do you want to accomplish? It sounds like all you want is to send an email?

Comment: @patrick whaaat?

I want to scan a server to retrive its links

Comment: Jak: So how exactly does one scan a server? What is the "server", a service or a computer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are interested in extracting anchor links from HTML document sent by a web server you could use [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to parse this document:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var document = new HtmlDocument();
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        using (var reader = new StringReader(client.DownloadString("http://www.google.com")))
        {
            document.Load(reader);
        }

        var anchors = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a");
        foreach (var anchor in anchors)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(anchor.Attributes["href"].Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: no - I ment to get a list or URLs of ALL existing files and folders on server. We have adress and port. (no HTML pages nothing - just server adress)